# creating a python dictionary from a list and comma separated line

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, dictionary

Is there a more *elegant* way in `python` to create a `dictionary` from a `list` and a `cs line` besides a loop?

```
my_master_list = ["ABC", "DEF", "GHI"]
my_list = ["field1", "field2", "field3"]
my_line = "test1,test2,test3"
my_dict = {}

for x in my_master_list:
    my_dict[x] = {}
    line_parts = my_line.split(",")
    n = 0
    for y in my_list:
        my_dict[x][y] = line_parts[n]
        n +=1

print my_dict
# {'ABC': {'field2': 'test2', 'field3': 'test3', 'field1': 'test1'}, 'GHI': {'field2': 'test2', 'field3': 'test3', 'field1': 'test1'}, 'DEF': {'field2': 'test2', 'field3': 'test3', 'field1': 'test1'}}
```

Comment: If I could, I'd accept both answers, thank you!

Comment: What is a `csvline`? I have a feeling you are not doing things in the most Pythonic way. Are you reading a csv with `open(file).read()`? You should look into the `csv` module, it's simple and much easier.

Comment: @Denziloe the line comes from a socket loop, I should  probably call it just cs line;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
d = {x:dict(zip(my_list, my_line.split(','))) for x in my_master_list}
        ^   ^                      ^
        |   |                     [1]--- creates a list from the string
        |   |
        |  [2]--- creates a tuple from two lists
        |
       [3]--- creates a dictionary from the tuples (key, value)
 ^
 |
[4] The overall expression is a dictionary comprehension.
```

Read about dict comprehensions in [PEP274](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/).

Comment: Cool solution. However,  and although I find dict and list comprehensions very elegant, one liners of such size have poor readability and should not be encouraged.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `zip` with a *dictionary comprehension*:

```
# construct the inner dictionary 
d = dict(zip(my_list, my_line.split(",")))

# construct the outer dictionary, if you don't want to make copies, you can use 
# {master_key: d ... } directly here just keep in mind they are referring to the same 
# object in this way
{master_key: d.copy() for master_key in my_master_list}

#{'ABC': {'field1': 'test1', 'field2': 'test2', 'field3': 'test3'},
# 'DEF': {'field1': 'test1', 'field2': 'test2', 'field3': 'test3'},
# 'GHI': {'field1': 'test1', 'field2': 'test2', 'field3': 'test3'}}
```